# detecting collision with a movie clip with transparent areas

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a project that involves a movie clip, which has transparent areas. Is there any way to get collisions on another object working so it only hits the opaque areas of this movie clip or is that asking too much? My current collision only counts the bounding box so the player cant really move as it get stuck in transparent areas

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer?  This is a very common question that  has plenty of answers and online resources to solve

Comment: Also, share an example of your code.  Most likely, hitTestPoint will do what you want with the shapeFlag argument set to true.   If not, you'll need to pixel collision checking.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I didn't include code coz I know mine doesn't work and I'll probably need something completely different.. most answers I found, I either didn't understand or involved some external the i don't know how to use...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MovieClip with transparent area, create another MovieClip that has smaller width and height than first one. Then, use this new MC for collision detection, you can set visibility to false. Use "enterFrame" function to make new MC follows your MC with transparent areas.

Comment: I still don't really understand it tho